# Its Possible Check Last Key On Firebase Real time Database?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Is it possible to validation firebase rule to accept only key more than highest price?

```
".validate": "!root.child('data/penawaran/'+$product_id+'/'+$price).exists() &&  root.child('data/penawaran/'+$product_id.val()  > newData.child('price').val() "
```

[image: Key Fireabase]

[image]

When i set new data like this

```
{
   "name":"name",
   "price":1000000000,
   "member_id":"1",
   "product_id":"79",
   "created_at":"2020-10-10 10:10:10"
}
```

always getting error no permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way in security rules to get a specific-but-unknown key. At the moment you will somehow have to know the key.

The best I can think of is keeping a single global `max-key` value somewhere, and then having that be updated at the same time as you create the new child node here.